# Using bind function in event listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery

I  have been writing a plugin,  and i really like this format

```
Function.prototype._onClick = function() {
  // do something
}

Fuction.prototype.addListner = function() {
   this.$element.on('click', this._onClick.bind(this));
}
```

the problem is sometimes i need the element being clicked and the main object. Doing as below i loose the dom element and not using bind looses the main object.

```
Fuction.prototype.addListner {
  this.$element.find('.some-class').on('click', this._onClick.bind(this));
}
```

To achieve that i go back to ugly version

```
    Fuction.prototype.addListner = function() {
      var self = this;
      this.$element.find('.some-class').on('click', function() {
        self._onClick($(this));   
      });
   }
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target So you still can use the `bind`-based solution and extract a target from the event object.

Comment: @zerkms can u give an example. I dont see how that is relevant.

Comment: `$(this) == $(e.target)`

Comment: @gerric updated the problem.. this is pointing to the new object being created not the root element

Comment: @gerric there is nothing to be set up on fiddle its just design pattern problem

Comment: Why dont you pass the element which being clicked as argument to `bind`? `this._onClick.bind(this, some_class)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [zerkms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251311/zerkms), you can use the event.target to achieve what you want.

When using [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/), the handler is :

> - handler
>
> Type: Function( Event eventObject [, Anything extraParameter ] [, ...
>   ] ) A function to execute when the event is triggered. The value false
>   is also allowed as a shorthand for a function that simply does return
>   false.

So your _onClick function will receive click event as its 1st parameter, then from `event.target`, you can now get the clicked item.

```js
var Test = function(sel) {
  this.$element = $(sel);
  this.value = 'My value is ' + this.$element.data('val');
};

Test.prototype.addListner = function() {
  this.$element.find('.some-class').on('click', this._onClick.bind(this));
}

Test.prototype._onClick = function(evt) {
  // Get the target which is being clicked.
   var $taget = $(evt.target);
   //
   console.log(this.value);
  // use $target to get the clicke item.
   console.log($taget.data('val'));
}




var test = new Test('#test');
test.addListner();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" data-val="divVal">
  <button class="some-class" data-val="Button-A">btnA</button>
  <button class="some-class" data-val="Button-B">btnB</button>
</div>
```

Comment: but i need the clicked element not this.$element which i already have, 'some-class' element is within that

Comment: @namankalkhuria Updated the answer, it should now give you both ele you want.